# How to delete function from DLL binary

Tags: c++, dll, binary, decompiling, disassembly

I've got a compiled dll file (dll binary) without source code. I have to **delete some functions** from this dll. Dll is written in C++.

For example, I've got Math.dll which contains 3 functions:

```
int Func1(int x);
int Func2(int x, int y);
double Func3(double x, double y);
```

I need to get new dll file with just one function:

```
int Func1(int x);
```

**All I've got is Math.dll - one binary dll file.**

Any tools or any methods to do that?

**Update**

I need to delete some functions because of several requirements:

- new dll contains just functions my application need
- new dll size has to be reduced

Comment: Why do you have to delete these functions? Well, you can change the header, that they can no longer be seen from the client code. But changing the binary in the way you're asking for isn't possible AFAIK.

Comment: I've updated my question. It's possible to do using asm and low-level programming, but I'm searching for a bit more simple and "high-level" solution.

Comment: The common procedure is rebuilding the DLL from the source code. A DLL is a regular executable, so it contains headers, code, data, and relocations, and removing a piece out of the middle will not work. You may be confusing it with a *library* file.

Comment: I think you cannot delete the functions inside DLL. What you can do is import the functions you need.

Comment: No _library_ file. I've got  just _binary_ .dll file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friends, here is solution works for me.

**Solution**
Step 1. Create new DLL project in, e.g. in Visual Studio
Step 2. Disassemble DLL binary (tools OllyDbg, IDA Pro)
Step 3. In new DLL project create new function with the same name as original function. Copy function Assembler code (from step 2) to new function as inlined assembly instructions
Step 4. Repeat step 3 for each function new DLL must contain
Step 5. Build DLL

**Example**

Step 2. Asm code

```
?Func1@@YAHH@Z proc near    ;GetSquaredNumber

arg_0= dword ptr  8

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
imul    eax, eax
pop     ebp
retn
?Func1@@YAHH@Z endp
```

Step 3. New DLL C++ code

```
__declspec(dllexport) int Func1(int x)    // GetSquaredNumber
{
    int y_res = 0;

    __asm
    {                           
        mov     eax, [x]
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp        
        imul    eax, eax
        pop     ebp
        mov [y_res], eax
    }

    return y_res;
}
```

Step 5. Build project!
Results: new dll contains just functions my application need and new dll size is reduced.

Answer (score 1):

The function you *want* to remove may also be used by the DLL internally. Since you do not have the source, you will have to disassemble the whole DLL to check this.

Once you have the analyzed disassembly, it should be a fairly straightforward process to remove unused parts, assemble the remainder, and put that in a DLL. But in all honesty, there is no reasonable circumstance in which this will help. "new dll size have to be reduced" is not a believable statement in this century. Size only matters for deep embedded systems, and those do not run Windows.

Comment: There are some reasons: 1) new dll contains just functions my application need  -> because I have to proof there is no malware within dll.   2) new dll size has to be reduced  -> because of small size decreases certification costs.